# How to groupby a dataframe by month while keeping other string columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

A sample of my dataframe is as follows:

```
|Date_Closed|Owner|Case_Closed_Count|
|2022-07-19|JH|1|
|2022-07-18|JH|2|
|2022-07-17|JH|5|
|2022-07-19|DT|3|
|2022-07-15|DT|1|
|2022-07-01|DT|1|
|2022-06-30|JW|30|
|2022-06-28|JH|2|
```

My goal is to get a sum of case count per owner per month, which looks like:

```
|Month|Owner|Case_Closed_Count|
|2022-07|JH|8|
|2022-07|DT|5|
|2022-06|JW|30|
|2022-06|JH|2|
```

Here is the code I got so far:

```
df = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Closed'])
month = df.Date_Closed.dt.to_period("M")
G = df.groupby(month).agg({'Case_Closed_Count':'sum'})
```

With the code above, I manage to get the case closed count groupby month, but how do I keep the owner column?

Comment: added a solution. did it help?

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

```
df['Date_Closed'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Closed'])
df.groupby([df['Date_Closed'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m'), 'Owner']).sum().reset_index()
```

```
    Date_Closed     Owner   Case_Closed_Count
0   2022-06            JH               2
1   2022-06            JW              30
2   2022-07            DT               5
3   2022-07            JH               8
```